# Erro biblioteca stdafx.h

Tags: c

Alguém sabe por que dá erro nessa biblioteca e como arrumar?

Está declarado assim no cabeçalho do codeblocks:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

#define TAM_PILHA 2
#define NUM_ENTRA 5

void empilha(int *pilha, int *topo, int valor)
{
if (*topo < TAM_PILHA)
{
    pilha[*topo] = valor;
    (*topo)++;
}
else
{
    printf("Pilha Cheia\n");
}
}

int desempilha(int *pilha, int *topo)
{
if (*topo > 0)
{
    (*topo)--;
    return pilha[*topo];
}
else
{
    printf("Pilha Vazia\n");
}
}

int main()
{
int pilha_par[TAM_PILHA], pilha_impar[TAM_PILHA], topo_par = 0, topo_impar = 0;
int i = 0, num_do_usuario = 0;
for (i = 0; i < NUM_ENTRA; i++)
{
    printf("\nEntre com um numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_do_usuario);

    if ((num_do_usuario % 2) == 0)
    {
        empilha(pilha_par, &topo_par, num_do_usuario);
    }
    else
    {
        empilha(pilha_impar, &topo_impar, num_do_usuario);
    }

}

printf("\n\nNumeros pares sao: ");
while (topo_par > 0)
{
    printf("%d ", desempilha(pilha_par, &topo_par));
}

printf("\n\nNumeros impares sao: ");
while (topo_impar > 0)
{
    printf("%d ", desempilha(pilha_impar, &topo_impar));
}

printf("\n\n");

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Aparece erro:

```
fatal error: stdafx.h: No such file or directory|
```

Comment: Coloca qual erro aparece.

Comment: Coloca o seu código completo, esse erro pode ter várias causas. `stdafx.h` é um cabeçalho [pré-compilado](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/h552b3ca.aspx) do visual studio, tem casos que não precisa dele, algumas vezes é necessário incluir `windows.h`. Não posso afirmar sem ver o código completo.

Comment: Ja coloquei aí o código inteiro para análise.

Comment: Esse header é gerado pelo VS, se tu abrir ele tu vai ver que ele contem outras declarações de headers, serve apenas como "atalho", pode adicionar o conteudo dele direto no teu projeto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stdafx.h` é usado pela implementação do Visual Studio de cabeçalhos pré-compilados. Em muitos casos esse pode ser evitado, especialmente se o seu projeto é pequeno e com poucas dependências.

Para resolver você pode copiar o arquivo `stdafx.h` da pasta do projeto Visual Studio para a pasta de projeto codeblocks e tente compilar.

Eu fiz o teste aqui, retirando:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
```

e incluindo `#include <stdio.h>`, funcionou normalmente.

Caso ainda não consiga resolver seu problema, tem esse [fórum do Code::Blocks](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=19034.0)  sobre a sua dúvida.

Comment: Resolveu mesmo, é muito chato o VS, CB muito melhor para essa linguagem, minha opinião, mais intuitivo. Obrigado.